# How to protect electronics on a beach holiday/vacation

Tags: electronic-items, beaches, vacations, water-sports

In a world full of personal electronics from mobile phones to cameras, does anyone have ideas to keep them safe from water and sand on seaside holidays? That is, besides:

1. Not bringing them (can't live without them)
2. Getting a friend to watch them (everyone in the party wants to swim)
3. Locking them in a rental car (generally not advised)
4. Leaving them unguarded in a box (someone may steal them)
5. Getting waterproof versions (bad value for non-holiday use)

Comment: I'd separate these into two questions - how to visit, and where to stay.

Comment: I don't get it. You just edited the question into something that has little to do with the original question. I'm not sure, but I don't think this is accepted in the SE community as the votes (and favorites) this question had were given for the original question (the one about Greece). If you have a new question just post it as a new question. This keeps the site organised and useful for future users.

Comment: What the? This was a volcano question! You MUST NOT do this - if you're going to ask a new question, ask it separately, don't just edit the former.  Now there are google links that will be confused, search terms going to the wrong place and the comments above are now incorrect as well.

Comment: I closed this question since it's really something you shouldn't do as others already pointed out. If you have a new question, please do not edit your old one, but ask a new question.

Comment: @Gnubie Dont forget to accept the answer as the correct answer if it has helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning in 1983, a British company called **[AquaPac](http://store.aquapac.net/)**  produce a range of protective  100% waterproof cases, bags and pouches designed to house all manner of portable electronics for such items such as mobile phones, cameras, Amazon Kindles, iPods etc. They believe in producing products that are designed to protect from the elements.

You won't have to leave your electronics at home, in the car etc, but can quite happily take them in the water with you.